# change wordpress homepage with product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

i have a i-craft wordpress theme for woocommerce

i like to set a statically homepage but the themes doesnt work very well in dashboard

i go to te index.php page of the theme and i like to change this:

```
<div class="blog-columns" id="blog-cols">
        <?php /* The loop normal posts */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-customcateg' ); //get_post_format() ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
```

with product of woocommerce but i dont know how can i do for display product

anyone help me ? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to emulate how WooCommerce displays its products via Shortcode, you could do this:

```
<div class="blog-columns" id="blog-cols">
    <?php /* The loop normal posts */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-customcateg' ); //get_post_format() ?>
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[product id="1"]') ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Just replace the 'id="1"' parameter with whatever product ID is associated with your product in WooCommerce

Comment: for multiple products, use this shortcode instead: [products ids="1, 2, 3, 4, 5"]